insomnia – v9.2.0 : add a pre request script
I'm trying to add a pre request script to my request in insomnia.
Initially this script only makes a console.log
If I execute my request without this prerequest script, I have a good response
if I add this pre request script, I get this error
Timeout: Hidden browser window is not responding
enter image description here
when I look in the console I see this error
hiddenWindowPort is undefined
I looked for how I could configure this port but I couldn't find any documentation on it.
how can I configure insomnia so that it executes this script?
thx

Can you share GET URL and Pre-Request Script code?

GET URL : http://localhost:8080/x/v1/callForIn
and the script :
console.log('ffffffffff' );
just a console.log

I tested it. The log did not display directly to Console of Dev Tool. It saved into AppData directory. You can see the detail location at Console's [network] Pre-request script in timeline Path. That path pointing text file. That text has log message.
